# How to make Google Chrome faster on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 for my late 2010 MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

1. I've only used 31.73 GB storage and there's more storage left (27.73 GB).
2. I regularly clean up and delete all caches.
3. I regularly do First aid.
4. I close all unused apps.
5. I regularly clean up my browsing history.

I only use this MacBook to watch YouTube videos and stream movies. My Safari is not efficient enough for this kind of productivity, hence why I use Chrome instead. Since I no longer have the option to upgrade, I was just wondering what can I do to make my Chrome experience faster and better. It's usable, but very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately, there’s not much you can do.**

You’re running a Late 2010 MacBook Air.  You never mentioned how much RAM you had, but the standard configuration was 2GB RAM upgradable to 4GB.  As the former was the most popular option, I’m assuming that’s what you’ve got.

Storage, First Aid and deleting caches are practically irrelevant here.  If you just streaming videos, other than cacheing the video to a temp file, doing these activities won’t speed things up.

**Your biggest issue is likely RAM and the lack of a modern operating system.**

RAM is required to hold your contents in a very fast medium for your CPU to access.  If you’re running out of memory, you have to write it to disk. The moment you have to do this, even to an SSD, things slow down.

Secondly, you likely need an updated browser to take advantage of the features sites like YouTube now utilize.  To use those new browsers, you need an updated OS.  You can try updating to High Sierra which will definitely help, but unfortunately, that’s the highest supported version on this Mac.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. Yeah I kinda expected about the RAM. I really like this MacBook because it has such sentimental value for me. Anyway, thank you so much for the help. I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: No worries, glad to help!  I wish you could get more life out of it.  Maybe a Linux or FreeBSD install could add some more years.  I’m running FreeBSD on a white MacBook,, so that might be an option for you